# How to get people to respond to an edit made to a question?

Tags: support, specific-question, asking-questions, unanswered-questions

I asked a question [here](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2069437/pythagoras-with-a-multivariable-function-errors/2069653&ved=0ahUKEwilwaT-4aPRAhULWBoKHYOZCwEQFggaMAA&usg=AFQjCNE0-Jjqx64OdRebH8jPxDt69RoPPQ&sig2=SuJHVieDDb3Yq5guvzKybQ) regarding pythagoras' theorem and the multivariable chain rule. I received some responses and edited my question to better reflect my new understanding. I commented on the answers referring to my new edit however I did not receive a response.

What should I do to receive an answer to my edited question, or should I perhaps have formulated this as another question?

Comment: You could offer a bounty.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  how do I do this?

Comment: I don't know, I've never done it. But there is a "help" menu on this page.

Comment: Right below the question post, it says "add a comment" and then "start a bounty" Click the latter and follow the instruction. (Note it costs some points.)

Comment: Since no answers were upvoted, your question will still show up in "unanswered" lists, and would get a bit more visibility than otherwise. I don't know much about the area to say that this is or isn't the case, just be careful to make sure when editing a question with answers, that you're not "moving the goalposts" too much. Finally, it's absolutely possible to realize that you didn't quite ask the question you wanted to ask, and use this to ask a new question that does better express what you're after (possibly removing the edit to this question).